# Getting confirmation via Bootstrap Modal before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

I am developing a website. Part of this website is an edit-form. When users want to submit their changes, I want a Bootstrap modal to appear and ask for confirmation.

[image: 1]

The form itself is HTML and the submit process is managed by a PHP code.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if($employee){
            $employee->firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
            $employee->lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
            $employee->fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
            $employee->email = $_POST['email'];
            $employee->empid = $_POST['empid'];
            $employee->newempid = $_POST['newempid'];
            $employee->manager = $_POST['manager'];
            $employee->status = $_POST['status'];
            $projectname = $_POST['project'];


            $SQL = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE project=" . "'" . $projectname . "'";
            $projectInfo = projects::FindByQuery($SQL);
            $projectInfo = $projectInfo[0];
            $employee->projectid = $projectInfo->id;


            if($employee->Update()){
                $Session->Message('Asset details has been updated');
                $Location = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                header("Location: ". $Location);
            } else {
                $Session->Message('Something went wrong');
            }
        }
    }
<form method='post' id='submitForm' >
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-outline">
                                        <label class="form-label ">Firstname</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>" class="form-control my-5">        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-outline ">
                                        <label class="form-label">Lastname</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>" class="form-control my-5">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-outline ">
                                        <label class="form-label">Fullname</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo $fullname;?>" class="form-control my-5">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-outline ">
                                        <label class="form-label">Status</label>
                                        <select class="form-control my-5" name='status' id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                            <option <?php if ($status == 'Active') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Active</option>
                                            <option <?php if ($status == 'Inactive') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Inactive</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>                            
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-outline ">
                                        <label class="form-label">Employee No.</label>
                                        <input type="test" name="empid" value="<?php echo $empid;?>" class="form-control my-5" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-outline ">
                                        <label class="form-label">BPM Employee No.</label>
                                        <input type="test" name="newempid" value="<?php echo $newempid;?>" class="form-control my-5">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-outline ">
                                    <label class="form-label">Email Addr.</label>
                                    <input type="test" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" class="form-control my-5">
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-outline ">
                                        <label class="form-label">Project</label>
                                        <select class="form-control my-5" name='project' id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                            <?php
                                                    foreach ($projects as $projectName){
                                                            $projectList = $projectName->project;
                                            ?>
                                                <option <?php if ($projectList == $project) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $projectList?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-outline ">
                                        <label class="form-label">Manager</label>
                                        <input type="test" name="manager" value="<?php echo $manager;?>" class="form-control my-5">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                
                            </div>

                            </div >
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-11">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <button type="submit" name="submit" id= "submit-button" class="btn btn-block bg-gradient-success mb-3 update" 
                                        data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#"   
                                        >Update</button>
                                        
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            
                        </form>
```

Here is the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="user-info-edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title font-weight-normal" id="exampleModalLabel">Please confirm</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close text-dark" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="" id="">Are you sure you want to submit changes? </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn bg-gradient-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="submit" value="update" class="btn bg-gradient-success">Submit</button>
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aster many tries, this idea kinda worked:
stop the "submit", when the submit button of the form is clicked and instead that triggers the Modal and then when the user clicks on the Submit button of the Modal, the form is being submitted via JS.
So I wrote this JS code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit-button').on('click', function(){
            $('#user-info-edit').modal('show');
        });
    });


  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').on('click', function(){
           
            let el = document.getElementById("submitForm");
                el.submit();
        });
    });
```

Now the Modal is shown, and after clicking on submit button in the modal the form is submitted. The issue is that I have a control system what to do in PHP when the form is submitted.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

apparently the $_POST['submit'] won't be sent with the method I am using so I changed the javascript to this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'submit=update'
        });
        let el = document.getElementById("submitForm");

            el.submit();

     
    });
});
```

now it seems the only thing that works is the that, but all the other values of $_POST are set to NULL. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Issue might be with the way you're using submitForm.addEventListener('submit', ...).

Instead of using addEventListener, you can simply use jQuery to intercept the form submission event and display the modal. Then, in the confirm button click event handler, you can submit the form using JavaScript's native submit method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Intercept the form submission event
    $('#submitForm').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission
        $('#user-info-edit').modal('show'); // Display the modal
    });

    // Submit the form when the user clicks the confirm button
    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
        $('#submitForm').off('submit').submit(); // Unbind the event handler and submit the form
    });
});
```